# How to overwrite CSS class in bootstrap popover close class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a close button in a bootstrap popover that takes the style of the bootstrap "btn btn-primary" class for popovers. I currently have the following implementation:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary close" href="#">Dismiss</button>
```

However, the style of the dismiss button is the style of the "close" class. It looks like this:

[image]

How can I change the style of the close button to btn and btn-primary without removing the close class, so that it looks like this?

[image]

Comment: write css to 'close' class with "!important"

Comment: @NitinDhomse any idea how to do this for the class btn?

Comment: use like,  .close { property-name : value !important; }  this will forcefully overrides your given css style and dont do  this will btn class. it may affect your original bootstrap css

Comment: is there also a way to do this without having to rewrite the btn class from scratch?

Comment: copy css of .btn class (modify with your style ) and apply it to new class and don't use btn class

Answer (score 1):

Write your custom css in style **style=""**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary close" href="#" style:"padding:8px">Dismiss</button>
```

Comment: but i want the css style of the btn btn-primary bootstrap class. is there I way I can do this without reimplementing the whole class?

Answer (score 1):

Try this css:

```css
.close {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(#007bcf, #0048cf) repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary close" href="#">Dismiss</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn.btn-primary.close {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(#007bcf, #0048cf) repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary close" href="#">Dismiss</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your style in same page if that is your question..

```
<style type="text/css">
  .close {
    //changes here
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without rewriting the full css class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `linear gradient` property.
[read more about linear gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

```css
.close {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(#429fdf, #043da9) repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary close" href="#">Dismiss</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

write your own class and apply styles to that class and call your css file after boostrap css might be that will help you..